# {{link}} is getting returned while scraping URLs from a webpage using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am scraping urls from a webpage like below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.investing.com/search/?q=Axon&tab=news"
response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

for s in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'articleItem'}):

    for a in s.find_all('div',{'class':'textDiv'}):
        for b in a.find_all('a',{'class':'title'}):
            print(b.get('href'))
```

And the output is coming like below

```
/news/stock-market-news/axovant-updates-on-parkinsons-candidate-axolentipd-1713474
/news/stock-market-news/digital-alley-up-24-on-axon-withdrawal-from-patent-challenge-1728115
/news/stock-market-news/axovant-sciences-misses-by-009-763209
/analysis/microns-mu-shares-gain-on-q3-earnings-beat-upbeat-guidance-200529289
/analysis/axon,-espr,-momo,-zyne-200182141
/analysis/factors-likely-to-impact-axon-enterprises-aaxn-q4-earnings-200391393
{{link}}
{{link}}
```

The problem is

1. All the URLs are not getting extracted
2. See the last two entries,Why is it so ?

Any solution to the above two problems ?

Comment: It is infinite loading on the site and when you make the get request i only load a part of it it is like this in the browser to but ehen you scroll down more of the page loads

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are making a HTTP request, while youtube renders the video data using JavaScript. To be able to parse to soup the JS content, you have to use the library which supports making requests and then rendering it with JS. Try to use the module `requests_html`. pypi.org/project/requests-html

Comment: How's youtube involved here ?

Comment: @Aiyaz the films are not the `HTTP` sequence. They are a `JavaScript` loaded sequence which means that they are dynamic content rendered through the script.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this problem is with selenium:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

And when selenium have scrolled down to the bottom of the page you read the pagesource and close selenium and parse pagesource with Beautifulsoup. You can also parse with selenium to.

First selenium and bs4:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time

PAUSE_TIME = 1
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/search/?q=Axon&tab=news')
lh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(PAUSE_TIME)


    nh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if nh == lh:
        break
    lh = nh
pagesourece = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesourece, "html.parser")

for s in soup.find_all('div',{'class':'articleItem'}):

    for a in s.find_all('div',{'class':'textDiv'}):
        for b in a.find_all('a',{'class':'title'}):
            print(b.get('href'))
```

And selenium only version:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import time

PAUSE_TIME = 1
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.investing.com/search/?q=Axon&tab=news')
lh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    time.sleep(PAUSE_TIME)


    nh = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if nh == lh:
        break
    lh = nh
pagesourece = driver.page_source




for s in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.articleItem'):

    for a in s.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.textDiv'):
        for b in a.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.title'):
            print(b.get_attribute('href'))
driver.close()
```

Note tou have to install [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) to rund this. If you want to have geckodriver in an other path then c:/program you have to change:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='c:/program/geckodriver.exe')
```

to your geckodriver path.

Comment: I will try this snippet and let you know if it works in my case.Thanks !